# Simple JWT Usage

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I have my Django backend authentication working (tested using curl and postman), but something eludes me. When sending test requests, the [docs](https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#usage) show username and password data being sent:

```
curl \
  -X POST \
  -H "Content-Type: application/JSON" \
  -d '{"username": "davidattenborough", "password": "boatymcboatface"}' \
  http://localhost:8000/api/token/
```

But, if I try to send an email and password instead, the response says that the username is a required field. Where and how can I change that behavior?

Thanks!

customUser model:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    pass
```

Comment: share your settings file

Comment: can you please also add your
Custom user model

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'authentication.CustomUser' model code for more details,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you define the two fields when you create your custom user model by inheriting from the `AbstractUser` model.

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email']
```